# Spring managed JSF converter as singleton

Tags: java, spring, jsf-2, converters, instantiation

My Spring-based web application uses JSF as a presentation layer. To make working Spring `@Autowired` annotation in my backing beans and to have a clean project structure I do **not** use any JSF-managed bean, converter nor a validator. All my beans has a `@Component` and `@Scope` annotation with a particular attributes.

## Problem:

One of my converters uses database and its `EntityManager` should be injected via `@Autowired`. **I figured out, that the converter is properly created by Spring, but JSF manages it either!** JSF creates its own instances of my converter and uses them instead of using the instances created by Spring.

### Note:

I reference the converter though EL evaluation: `<f:converter binding="#{myConverter}"/>`

### Environment:

My environment is Oracle JDK 6, 64b Linux OS, com.sun JSF 2.1 implementation, Spring 3.1.3.

## Questions:

1. Why JSF creates its own instances of my converter when I reference it via `#{myConverter}`
2. How did JSF figure out the class of converter because I didn't used `@FacesConverter` neither defined it in `faces-config.xml`?
3. Is there any way to force JSF to use only Spring-managed instances?

---

## Code to reproduce:

MyConverter.java

```
@Scope( "singleton" )
@Component( "myConverter" )
public class MyConverter implements Converter {

    private MyBean bean;

    public MyConverter() {
        System.out.println( "MyConverter created with no arg constructor" );
    }

    @Autowired
    public MyConverter( MyBean bean ) {
        System.out.println( "MyConverter created with parametrized constructor" );
        this.bean = bean;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject( FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value ) {
        System.out.println( "Bean value is " + bean );
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString( FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value ) {
        System.out.println( "Bean value is " + bean );
        return value.toString();
    }
}
```

JSF index.xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

<h:body>

    <h:form>

        <h:inputText value="#{myBean.text}">
            <f:converter binding="#{myConverter}"/>
        </h:inputText>

        <h:commandButton value="Create" action="#{myBean.action}"/>

    </h:form>

</h:body>

</html>
```

Comment: That's strange enough, seems like the bean must be managed by Spring. What is your environment? And also, how to you find out that your converter beans are created twice?

Comment: As I wrote, all my beans are declared to be managed by Spring, including Converters. When you look at the code to reproduce it, you can see that `MyConverter` has 2 constructors. Spring chooses the parametrized one, JSF the another one. And then it is enough to watch logs. By the way Converter is not created twice, it is created once by Spring and many times (each request) by JSF. The environment specification I added to the question description.

Comment: Try setting `@Autowired` on a field, or a getter method instead of setting it on constructor, retain only null-arg constructor and referr to the converter inside your element, like `<h:inputText converter="#{myConverter}"/>`. This configuration is working consistently in my projects. Also, ensure that `org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener` and `org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener` classes are present in your web.xml.

Comment: I tried `@Autowired` also on field/getter etc. but it doesn't solve the issue. That is that JSF create instance on their own even when they shouldn't. That causes the instance is not managed by Spring so DI is not performed. I need to use `<f:converter/>` because not all components has `converter` attribute. Both listeners already are in my web.xml.